# In Dawn of the Dead (2004) how do we account for the behaviour of Andy, the gunshop owner?

Tags: zombie, dawn-of-the-dead

You will recall the Andy who was marooned across from the mall and amused his distant friends with sharp-shooting was bitten but still held up the whiteboard with which they they had been communicating.

It seems to me that he had already turned and if so, does this show some sentience/memory in zombies, maybe stronger in the newly dead?

Comment: He was infected/dying, but not yet dead.

Comment: I am not sure on the timing. That would certainly be an explanation but there is reason also to believe that he had turned -- it happens very fast after death.

Comment: You may find this of interest; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FmS5WjuK6s&list=RD5FmS5WjuK6s#t=94

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. The [script](http://www.horrorlair.com/movies/scripts/dawnofthedead_2004.pdf) indicates that he'd turned (after bleeding to death), then *subsequently* written the message.

> **KENNETH:** *What a minute. I see him. He's on the roof. I think he's writing something.*
>
> [POV BINOCULARS]
>   We see Andy, his back to us, working on a dry erase
>   board. **He turns and holds it up. The board is smeared with blood. His
>   eyes dead. Andy has turned.**
>
> [ON THE ROOF]
>   **MICHAEL:** *What does the sign say?*
>
> **KENNETH:** *Tell her to get out of there, now.*

Comment: What is poignant is the idea that some vestige of sentience allowed him to warn his friends that he had turned; whether he meant to or not, there is nothing that he could have written while alive that was as eloquent as what he "wrote" as a zombie.

Answer (score 2):

Along with Valorum noting that the script may have indicated some degree of volition, the 1985 sequel *[Day of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_Dead_(1985_film))* and the 2005 sequel, *[Land of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Dead)* also introduced the plot point that the zombies will sometimes exhibit ingrained behavior from life. Bub, a former soldier, was able to fire a gun, and saluted afterwards. The zombies will still stop to watch fireworks overhead, and "Big Daddy" is able to use his repeated filling of gas tanks as an offensive weapon. Similarly, Andy had been holding up the board daily for days, and it's entirely possible that, as a zombie, he just kept doing that.

Comment: The question is whether that was completely "muscle memory" or whatever or if some spark of intelligence allowed him to warn his friends of what had happened to him. Alternatively, being that he wanted to eat living humans, that spark of intellect could have been used to lure them to him. Land of the Dead shows zombies with definite residual intelligence, while in Dawn it is speculative.

Comment: Yeah. The "of the Living Dead" series leaned into the intelligent zombies a bit earlier. "Send more paramedics" and all that. :-D

Comment: Inexplicably, Living Dead zombie seemed roughly of human intelligence. I found that series, with the impossibility of actually finally dying (perhaps) kind of intense and not too enjoyable -- one entry has a bitten girl and her boyfriend going into a furnace together -- kind of unpleasant.